# sort array with multi properties (descending date, name)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Could you please help correct the below code?

```
var arr = 

    [
      { created: '2020-09-28', title: 'title13' },
      { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title12' },
      { created: '2020-09-29', title: 'title8' },
      { created: '2020-09-29', title: 'title7' },
      { created: '2020-09-28', title: 'title6' },
      { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title1' },
      { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title13' },
      { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title2' },
    ];

function sortByValue(arr){
     var sortedArray = [];
     for(var i in arr)
     {
        sortedArray.push([arr[i], arr[i].created, arr[i].title]);
     }
     var sortedArraydata= [];
     sortedArraydata = sortedArray.sort();

     var finalarray=[];
     for (var i in sortedArraydata)
     {
        finalarray.push(sortedArraydata[i][0]);
     }
     return finalarray;
   }
sortByValue(arr);
```

The expectation is to sort by descending date and name properties. Here is what I am trying to achieve.
Output:

```
[
  { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title1' },
  { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title2' },
  { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title12' },
  { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title13' },
  { created: '2020-09-29', title: 'title7' },
  { created: '2020-09-29', title: 'title8' },
  { created: '2020-09-28', title: 'title6' },
  { created: '2020-09-28', title: 'title13' },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) :-)

```js
let arr = [
  { created: '2020-09-28', title: 'title13' },
  { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title12' },
  { created: '2020-09-29', title: 'title8' },
  { created: '2020-09-29', title: 'title7' },
  { created: '2020-09-28', title: 'title6' },
  { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title1' },
  { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title13' },
  { created: '2020-09-30', title: 'title2' },
]

let sorted = arr.sort((a, b) =>

  // sort by created desc
  (new Date(b.created) - new Date(a.created)) 

  // if 0 (a tie), sort by title asc
  || a.title.localeCompare(b.title) 
)

console.log(sorted)
```